# Queueing Promises with P-Queue node module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using node-fetch to make a HEAD request to an Amazon bucket to check the status of a file, but I am trying to set up the module [P-Queue](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-queue) to give me control over concurrency.

I have an array, `resources`, that contain all of my data including file paths to check within that bucket. Then map the array like so:

```
resources.map((resource) => {
    queue
        .add(validateImage(resource))
        .catch((err) => console.error(`Failed to add resource to queue: ${err}`));
});
```

And this is what my `validateImage` function looks like:

```
const validateImage = (resource) => {
    const path = `https://${bucketUrl}/${env}/${resource.path}`;
    verbose && console.log(`Fetching resource: ${path}`);
    return fetch(
        path,
        {
            method: 'HEAD',
            timeout
        }
    )
    .then(res => {
        validatedResources.push({
            ...resource,
            statusCode: res.status
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        validatedResources.push({
            ...resource,
            error: err.type
        });
    });
}
```

But whenever I run this script I get the error `Failed to add resource to queue: TypeError: fn is not a function` as many times as I have resources.

I've checked that what is being returned from validateImage is a Promise and I also tried rewriting the example from the p-queue github to use fetch (suspecting that being the reason):

```
const PQueue = require('p-queue');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const queue = new PQueue({concurrency: 1});

queue.add(() => fetch(
    'http://sindresorhus.com'),
    { method: 'HEAD'}
).then(() => {
    console.log('Done: sindresorhus.com');
});

queue.add(() => fetch('http://ava.li')).then(() => {
    console.log('Done: ava.li');
});
```

This does work, so I'm not really sure where to look anymore?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`queue.add` expects a function, however you are passing a Promise.

When you call `queue.add(validateImage(resource))`, the engine first evaluates `validateImage(resource)`, which returns a Promise. Then it evaluates `queue.add(<returned promise>)`.

Simply change the call to an arrow function: `queue.add(() => validateImage(resource))`

Comment: Oh, wow it was staring in my face all the time. Did not even realize that I was passing an arrow function in the example below. Thanks!